# TS2339: Property 'posts' does not exist on type

Tags: typescript, vue.js, ionic-framework, vuejs3, ionic5

This is my code where I try to call API in ionic 5 with Axios

```js
import axios from "axios";

import {
  IonCard,
  IonCardContent,
  IonCardSubtitle,
  IonCardTitle
} from "@ionic/vue";

export default {
  name: "Tab1",
  components: {
    IonCard,
    IonCardContent,
    IonCardSubtitle,
    IonCardTitle
  },
  data() {
    return { posts: [] };
  },

  created() {
    axios.get("http://gautammenaria.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts").then(response => {
      this.posts = response.data;
    });
  }
};
```

Get this error (Also get data as expected )

***TS2339: Property 'posts' does not exist on type '{ name: string; components: {***

Not sure what it is

Comment: `export default Vue.extend({ })` would make more sense if you're going to be using typescript.

Comment: which vue version are you using?

Comment: i am using vue 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should build your component using `defineComponent` function to get types inference :

```
import axios from "axios";

import {
  IonCard,
  IonCardContent,
  IonCardSubtitle,
  IonCardTitle
} from "@ionic/vue";

import {defineComponent} from 'vue'

export default defineComponent({
  name: "Tab1",
  components: {
    IonCard,
    IonCardContent,
    IonCardSubtitle,
    IonCardTitle
  },
  data() {
    return { posts: [] };
  },

  created() {
    axios.get("http://gautammenaria.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts").then(response => {
      this.posts = response.data;
    });
  }
});
```